# "server failed to respond" in JMeter http sampler (related to timers) being analyzed by Wireshark

Tags: tcp, jmeter, wireshark

I'm observing "strange" behaviour of network. Each even http request sent by JMeter as part of thread is lost ("server failed to respond") error. The error is observed using `constant timer` and not observed using `constant throughput timer` when each results in about one http request per second. Setting delay of 2 seconds between requests makes error go away (probably timeout kicks in), then number of lines in Wireshark log grows from 29 to 51. So one way with same frequency results in no errors and other in 100%. The issue is not that obvious in other settings and I want to use that setup to find root cause of the problem.

As the internal network data etc are of sensitive nature I do not think I get share complete Wireshark logs. In Wireshark main screen visual difference between successful run and failed one starts with time for 2nd request (significant gap in timeline before that) when in success we send data but in failed one we get `Encrypted Alert` packet. I failed to find differences in data send from client side in packets immediately before such difference by manual looking at contents of packets. The task is new to me and highly technical so even when I found some posts related to `Encrypted Alert` I could not apply them to my situation. Please tell what additional info from Wireshark etc. needed to find cause of the problem and to find out what is different in way client makes requests in both cases. See screens of wireshark, differences start at line 19:

failed 2nd http:
[image: failed 2nd http]
successful both http:
[image: successful both http]

Answer (score 0):

In order to decrypt the traffic using Wireshark you will need to:

1. [Get RSA private key for the website you're testing](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9834/69/how-can-i-find-the-private-key-for-my-ssl-certificate)
2. [Feed the RSA private key to Wireshark](https://wiki.wireshark.org/TLS#RSA_Keys)

In the majority of cases it would be much easier to use JMeter and Java debugging mechanisms, for example:

1. Add the next line to *system.properties* file:

   ```
   javax.net.debug=all
   ```

   this way you will get a lot of information regarding SSL/TLS handshakes, certificates used, etc. in the [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout))
2. [Uncomment (or add) the next line in log4j2.xml](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/)

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
   ```

   this way you will get Wireshark-level of details on each and every incoming and outgoing [network packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_packet)